Do non-trivial finite vector spaces necessarily involve modular arithmetic?
I'm exploring the properties of finite vector spaces and have observed that non-trivial finite vector spaces typically involve operations defined modulo some number, due to their dependence on finite fields which inherently use modular arithmetic.
My question is:

Is it true that all non-trivial finite vector spaces require the use
of modular arithmetic? Can a non-trivial finite vector space exist
without involving modulo operations?

I understand that the trivial vector space, which contains only the zero vector, does not require modular operations. However, for any non-trivial vector space defined over a finite field, it seems unavoidable. I'm looking for a deeper understanding of why this is the case, or if there are exceptions to this rule.

What do you mean by finite vector spaces, finitely many elements, or finite dimension? In the first case, we must have a finite scalar field $ \mathbb{F}$ since all multiples are again vectors in our vector space. For the same reason, we have infinitely many elements in the vector space if $\mathbb{F}$ contains infinitely many scalars. So, the answer to your question is yes. However, you can also have modular arithmetic AND an infinite vector space, just not a finite vector space with an infinite field. A finite dimension is a different topic.

Not all finite fields "inherently use modular arithmetic" (e.g. finite field of order $p^k$ for $k\geq2$ and $p$ prime)

@MariusS.L. I am asking about these vector spaces

@hanugm Then this is what I answered to. If $V$ is a finite set, then $\mathbb{F}$ must be finite, too, and this is only the case if $\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{p\text{ times}}=0$ for some prime $p,$ which is basically the definition of modular arithmetic.

@morrowmh That's wrong. A field of order $p^k$ uses operations modulo $p,$ which is modular.

@MariusS.L. I thiunk morrowmh's point is that $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ is not just $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

(Or $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^k$ I suppose. I've seen both of those mistakes before.)

Since the vector space is finite, its scalar field is finite. A finite ring $R$  has finite characteristic $n,$ (= cardinality of image of $\Bbb Z$ in $R)$ hence $R$ is a $,\Bbb Z/n$ algebra, i.e. scalar arithmetic can be done $!\bmod n.\ \ $

The link given by @hanug uses the notation of a vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{F}.$ The scalar multiplication is an operation
$$
\mathbb{F}\times V \longrightarrow V
$$
with $1\cdot v= v$ for all $v\in V.$ If $V$ is finite as a set, an additively written group of finite order, then
$$
\mathbb{F}\cdot V= \{c\cdot v\,|\,c\in \mathbb{F} \wedge v\in V\} \subseteq V
$$
must be finite, too. We thus get for a vector $v\neq 0$ which exists since we assume $V\neq \{0\}$ that particularly $\mathbb{F}\cdot v$ is finite and we must have a repetition:
$$
n\cdot v=\underbrace{(1+\ldots+1)}_{n \text{ times}}\cdot v=\underbrace{(1+\ldots+1)}_{m \text{ times}}\cdot v=m\cdot v
$$
for some positive integers $n,m.$ This means $(m-n)\cdot v= 0$ for an integer $k:=m-n$ which we may assume to be positive (to better handle it).
But from $k\cdot v=\underbrace{(1+\ldots+1)}_{k \text{ times}}\cdot v=0$ we get
$$
\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{k \text{ times}}=0
$$
This is an equation in $\mathbb{F}$ now. It means that $\mathbb{F}$ is of characteristic $n.$ Since $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, one can show that $n$ must be a prime $n=p$. (Hint for @hanugm: If $n=a\cdot b\; (a,b>1)$ show that $n$ cannot have a multiplicative inverse.) So we have now that
$$
\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{p \text{ times}}=0\qquad (*)
$$
which is the definition of modular arithmetic.
Notes:
a) It does not mean that $\mathbb{F}$ has only $p$ elements. It only means that $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{1,2,\ldots,p=0\}\subseteq \mathbb{F}.$ The field itself can have $p^k$ many elements, but (*) still holds.
b) It does not mean that all vector spaces in which (*) holds are necessarily finite. $V$ can have infinite dimensions (e.g. functions as vectors) and it can have an infinite field $\mathbb{F}$ (e.g. if we add $\pi$ and all its powers - positive and negative - to the field).
